# Join returns empty values

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables,

```
Table: Person

+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| PersonId    | int     |
| FirstName   | varchar |
| LastName    | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
PersonId is the primary key column for this table.
```

and

```
Table: Address

+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| AddressId   | int     |
| PersonId    | int     |
| City        | varchar |
| State       | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
AddressId is the primary key column for this table.
```

I want to write a SQL query for a report that provides the following information for each person in the Person table, regardless if there is an address for each of those people:

```
FirstName, LastName, City, State
```

### What have I done?

```
# Write your MySQL query statement below
SELECT Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Address.City, Address.State
FROM Person
INNER JOIN Address ON Person.PersonId=Address.PersonId;
```

For some reason the join returns empty data. Please give hints not solution.

Comment: Change your inner join into left outer join

Comment: Other than changing your inner join to a left join, are sure that anyone in your `person` table in fact has a matching address?  If not, you'll get an empty set from an inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the "regardless if there is an address" phrase, you are requesting a LEFT JOIN.

You requested hints, not a solution, so I'll leave just a link to [a Wikipedia article on SQL Joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) that should point you in the right direction.